# The same text has different byte size

Tags: c#, file, byte, savefiledialog

I have simple txt file, read this content, do with them some operation (for example encode and decode) and save result in file. When I compare its two files in beyond compare I see that content the same. But sizes of files are different. Why? And how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: How you read and write the file?

Comment: Ray, do you need an answer or just a guess?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria `File.ReadAllText(file, Encoding.UTF8);` `File.WriteAllText(fileName, dest_txt.Text, Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @I4V I know that in new file was inserted some kind of encoding symbol. But I don't understand how read and write file in the same encoding and with the same order of characters get different size of byte

Comment: @Tzach answer it's correct, the best you can do is comparing files and see what changes (I was thinking about encoding and even you load and save file with same encoding can be the cause)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There can be many reasons for that, for example different encoding, or maybe one is using `\r\n` and the other uses only `\n`.

Use Hex Compare in BeyondCompare to find out exactly.

Comment: In addition to line breaks, there are also byte-order-marks on certain text encoding, so the first few bytes of the file may be different.

Comment: Can you tell exactly what is the difference? Have you used the Hex Compare?

Comment: @Tzach In source file 0D 0A, in result file 0A

Comment: This is `\r\n` replaced with `\n` only. Make sure that when you create the `dest_txt.Text` string you use `Environment.NewLine` and not just `\n`